# How to Colorize String Results in JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

In my jsp file below last ***<%=rs.getString("results")%>*** as **results** returns 3 different results as W,L and D.
How can I show W for green, L for red and D for yellow for using if condition and/or other statement?

If any problem I added code to this link: https://codeshare.io/EBbOyO

Thanks in advance to those who will help.

```
    <table class="table ">
  <thead>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <th class="text-center col-xs-1" style="width:1%" scope="col">Week</th>
      <th class="text-center col-xs-1"  scope="col">Match Date</th>
      <th  class="text-left  col-xs-1" scope="col">Home</th>
      <th  class="text-left  col-xs-1" scope="col">Away</th>
      <th class="text-center col-xs-1" style="width:5%"  scope="col">Home Score</th>
      <th class="text-center col-xs-1" style="width:5%"  scope="col">Away Score</th>
            <th class="text-center col-xs-1" style="width:5%"  scope="col">Result</th>
    </tr>

<%
    if(request.getParameter("uid")!=null)
    {
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("uid")); 
        String dburl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teams"; 
        String dbusername="root";
        String dbpassword="Fener2013"; 

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,dbusername,dbpassword); 
            PreparedStatement pstmt=null; //create statement

            pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select m.week, m.match_date, t1.team_name hometeam, m.home_score as homescore, t2.team_name awayteam,m.away_score as awayscore,l.league_name,  CASE WHEN m.home_score > m.away_score THEN 'W' WHEN m.home_score < m.away_score THEN 'L' WHEN m.home_score = m.away_score THEN 'D' END AS results from matches m join teams  t1 on m.home_team_id = t1.team_id join teams  t2 on m.away_team_id = t2.team_id join   leagues l on l.league_id = m.league_id where  m.home_team_id = ? or m.away_team_id = ?");          
            pstmt.setInt(1,id);
            pstmt.setInt(2,id); 
            ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery(); 

            while(rs.next())
            {
                %> 
  <tbody>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="something col-xs-1" style="width:1%"><%=rs.getString("m.week")%></td>
      <td class="something col-xs-1" ><%=rs.getString("m.match_date")%></td>
      <td class="text-left col-xs-1" ><%=rs.getString("hometeam")%></td>
      <td class="text-left col-xs-1" ><%=rs.getString("awayteam")%></td>
      <td class="something col-xs-1" style="width:5%"  ><%=rs.getString("homescore")%></td>
      <td class="something col-xs-1" style="width:5%"  ><%=rs.getString("awayscore")%></td>
<!--     Below Strings returns 3 different result as W,L and D. How can I show W for green, L for red and D for yellow for using if or other statement? -->
         
    <td class="something col-xs-1" style="width:5%"> <span class="label label-success"><%=rs.getString("results")%></span></td>
    
    </tr>
         </tbody>
                <%
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
%>
</table>
```

Comment: How would you do this in plain html?

Comment: In plain HTML you cannot use if condition I guess. Currently I am using all resuts as green label color.

Comment: JSP ends up generating plain HTML (perhaps with some javascript in it) so you must understand how to do what you want in plain HTML.  Then you can code your JSP to generate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class='label label-success color-<%=rs.getString("results")%>'><%=rs.getString("results")%></span>
```

You can pass result into class, and add styling

```
<style>
.color-W{
color:green;
}
.color-L{
color:red;
}
.color-D{
color:yellow;
}
</style>
```